# AWK. Loop through a directory and sum columns

Tags: windows, batch-file, awk, printf

I am trying to sum a column and write the output along with the filename. I have written the following line which works well and outputs the sum. I am struggling with 2 things. passing the filename along with the output and how do i loop through the current directory and process only *.txt files. Pls note that i am running this through a batch file (.bat) in windows 7. Thks

```
awk -F"\t" "{ sum+=$2} END {printf ("""%%15d""",sum) >>"output.txt"}" input.TXT
```

Also how can one pass the output of printf ("""%%15d""",sum) to a variable?

Comment: @shellter. have added the tags as u suggested. Could you let me know how to just pass the filename in the above code. I can live without the loop and do it manually. AWK has opened my eyes to a whole new world of processing files and its superfast even on windows. Cheers

Comment: You should not need a loop, unless Windows has even more issues than I suspect, since one awk execution can parse multiple files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`how do i loop through the current directory and process only *.txt files` is a question for your OS, not for awk.

Each file name is stored in the FILENAME variable within awk.

To avoid nightmarish Windows quoting issues, put your script in a file (e.g. named `foo.awk`) and then run that file using `awk -f foo.awk <input_files>` where `<input_files>` represents the list of input files as provided by your OS (in UNIX it'd be `*.txt` or similar).

Based on the script you posted, foo.awk would contain:

```
BEGIN { FS="\t" }
{ sum[FILENAME] += $2 }
END {
    for (i=1;i<ARGC;i++)
        printf "%s %15d\n", ARGV[i], sum[ARGV[i]] >> "output.txt"
}
```

BUT I suspect you're mis-using ">>" and really want ">" instead. You might also want to take the `> "output.txt"` out of the awk script completely and just redirect the output on the command line so you can see both the input and the output files in the same place.

I don't know what `how can one pass the output of printf ("""%%15d""",sum) to a variable?` means.

To use print-like formatting and assign the result to a variable you'd use `sprintf()` instead of `printf`, e.g.:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ foo = sprintf("%s",3.79); print foo}'
3.79

$ awk 'BEGIN{ foo = sprintf("%d",3.79); print foo}'
3

$ awk 'BEGIN{ foo = sprintf("%.4f",3.79); print foo}'
3.7900
```

Comment: Summing the column resulted in numbers in scientific notation. I then read the manual to use printf %d but then that was outputting the values directly to the file. wanted to know how to pass it to a variable so that i could then manipulate it. is there no way to format a number and put it into a variable other than printf. Thks

Comment: @user2473726 I updated my answer to show how to use `sprintf()`, see if that answers your question.

Comment: Thats perfect. Learnt something new. Thks

Comment: Also see @sudo_Os answer if you have a reasonably new version of GNU awk (`gawk`) since that would support `ENDFILE` and then you wouldn't need `sum` to be an array and then loop through all of the input file names in the `END` section.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `GNU awk` the variable `FILENAME` contains the name of the current file being read. If you pass all the files at once to `awk` then you would use `ENDFILE` instead of `END`:

```
$ awk '{sum+=$1}ENDFILE{print FILENAME,sum; sum=0}' file1 file2
file1 6
file2 15
```

Where `file1` and `file2` are:

```
$ cat file1
1
2
3

$ cat file2
4
5
6
```

Awk splits on whitespace so you probably don't need to explicitly set the value of `FS` and [**EdMorton**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18791018/1066031) already covered the redirection `>` vs `>>`. It's also worth noting that `printf` is a statement not a function in `awk`. The script uses Linux quoting not Windows but ideas are the same.

To get around Windows quoting you could put your script in a file, say `sum.awk`

```
BEGIN { 
    FS="\t" 
}     
{ 
    sum+=$2
}  
END {
    printf "%15d",sum >> "output.txt"
}
```

And call it like:

```
awk -f sum.awk <files>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk "{sum+=$2} END {printf(\"%15d\n\", sum)}" *.txt > "output.txt"
```

this works nicely on the Windows cmd commando prompt. To use it in a Windows command language script (aka "Batch") you must double the percent signs.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('awk "{sum+=$2} END {printf(\"%%15d\n\", sum)}" *.txt') do set "sum=%%a"
echo %sum%
```